# How to save and load multiple credentials using Locksmith?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, keychain

I'm using a basic library called [Locksmith](https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith). Although, it seems as if all the examples handle a single username and password for the application, instead of multiple.

Example:

```
let dictionary = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount("myUserAccount")
```

The above just returns a username and password for that particular account. How would I use Locksmith to save and load many user accounts?

Answer (score 1):

For multiple user accounts on the same device, I'll store and load data using a key that includes something unique about each user. Instead of "myUserAccount", I'll save and load data with a key like `"myUserAccount-userId123"` or `"myUserAccount-JimSmith"`.